# Issue with scanner in main method vs in constructor java?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

**SOLVED**

I'm having an issue using Scanners nextInt() method in a class constructor.
it works fine if used in a main method like the code below however when doing the same thing in a constructor I get an inputmismatchexception,
what could be the possible issues?

```
public class QuickTest{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


  java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File("tograph.txt");
  java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(myFile);

  int numberOfPoints = input.nextInt();

  String[] myArray = new String[numberOfPoints];

   //need to use nextLine once after reading in number of points to get  to next line

  input.nextLine();

  int count = 0;
  while(input.hasNext() == true){

     myArray[count] = input.nextLine();
     count++;
  }

  input.close();

  for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

     System.out.println(myArray[i]);
  }
```

the class version

```
public class MyGraph{

 //filled with strings from file
 String[] points;
 java.io.File file;
 java.util.Scanner input;
 //length of points array
 int numPoints;

 public MyGraph(String file){

   this.file = new java.io.File(file);
   this.input = new java.util.Scanner(file);

   this.numPoints = this.input.nextInt();
   this.points = new String[this.numPoints];

   fillGraphArray();


  }

  //after getting the number of vertices we populate the array with   every
 //line after those points untill the end
 private void fillGraphArray(){

   //used once after reading nextInt()
   this.input.nextLine();

   int count = 0;
   while(this.input.hasNext() == true){

     points[count] = input.nextLine();

     count++;
   }

   input.close();
}

//test method to be delted later
public String[] getPoints(){

   return this.points;
}

//may need a method to close the file
}
```

When I use the debugger the main method version will get the number of points from the file and then fill the array with a string from each following line in the file however the class version throws the exception

Comment: You are not showing the `new` call ...

Comment: Try to change this.input= new scanner (file) with this.input=new scanner (this.file).

Comment: Thanks George I should have realized that

Comment: When you have enough reputation, give an self answer and accept it, instead of literally writing "solved", which the system doesn't understand, and treats instead as unsolved.